# JSF pasing input to bean doesn't work

Tags: jsf, ejb

Hello I am trying to achieve something very basic and failing in the proces. I Want to pass username and password from JSF to bean and then use them in method from the bean to add user to database . Unfortunetly input doesn't seam to reach the bean at all and i get `javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException` because neither password nor login can be null.
**Log4j logs show that arguments are indeed null**

```
[2017-05-03T16:50:18.948+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(1)] [timeMillis: 1493823018948] [levelValue: 800] [[

  464239 [http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(1)] DEBUG pl.lodz.p.it.ssbd2017.ssbd06.mok.facades.AbstractFacade  - log4j: login null]]



[2017-05-03T16:50:18.949+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(1)] [timeMillis: 1493823018949] [levelValue: 800] [[

  464240 [http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(1)] DEBUG pl.lodz.p.it.ssbd2017.ssbd06.mok.facades.AbstractFacade  - log4j: passwordnull]]
```

**Here is the code from JSF**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<body>
<f:view>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="LOGIN: "/>
        <h:inputText value="#{createBean.login}"/>
        <h:outputLabel value="PASSWORD : "/>
        <h:inputText value="#{createBean.password}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="Register" action="#{createBean.create()}"/>

    </h:form>

</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

**and here from bean**

```
@Named("createBean")
@RequestScoped
public class CreateBean {

    @Inject
    private MOKEndpointLocal mokEndpoint;

    private String login;
    private String password;

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CreateBean.class);


    public CreateBean() {
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

//    public String getTest() {
//        return "test";
//    }

    public void create() {
        log.debug("logBean: login  " + login);
        log.debug("logBean: pass  " + password);
        mokEndpoint.create(login, password);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think if you use @Named("createBean") , it is done , otherwise I should see your project configuration

Comment: unfortunetly it didn't help what kind of configuration files would you like to see `web.xml`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what type is `RequestScoped`?

Comment: Accourding to "Java EE 7 Development With NetBeans" 
`Request scoped beans are shared through the duration of a single request. A single request could refer to an HTTP request, an
invocation to a method in an EJB, a web service invocation, or sending a JMS message. to a message-driven bean.`

Comment: What @BuhakeSindi means is the package of the `@RequestScoped` annotation

Comment: Narrow down your problem. What do the debug statements in the create method show? The right values? Then this question is in no way jsf related (since it made sure the values came from the client to the server and hence it did its job). And with _"JSF to bean"_ you mean from CreateBean to the ejb?

Comment: there are two `RequestScoped` annotation by default. The JSF one takes place in the javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped class and the CDI one is in the `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped` class. For CDI beans (Named annotated) you should use the annotation from package `javax.enterprise.context`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks a lot for help guys as it turns out you were right about `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`. After jsf started magically working I checked out previous comits on my repository and diff showed me that i was using `javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped` before, although i don't remember changing it. Now it works just fine.

Thanks again and take care!